# Access to restricted NTFS partition after reinstall (lost SID?)

Tags: windows, ntfs

After reinstall of a Windows Vista computer, trying to access a second NTFS partition (D:) is impossible (Access Denied). The partition had access restricted to only one user before reinstall.

I'm not an expert on how this works, but I guess it could have something to do with the old machine SID being lost, and hence the user SID associated with the permissions on the partition.

How can I recover from this and access the data on D:?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take ownership of the files and folders on the drive. From Microsoft:

To take ownership of a folder:

1.Right-click the folder that you want to take ownership of, and then click Properties.

2.Click the Security tab, click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.

3.Click Edit.  If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

4.Click the name of the person you want to give ownership to.

5.If you want that person to be the owner of files and subfolders in this folder, select the Replace owner on subcontainers and objects check box.

6.Click OK.

Comment: Oh, that simple :-). That worked (except in this case I had to right-click the actual drive and go into the Security tab, but the principle is the same). Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...